# Spring + WebSocket Error 400

Tags: spring, sockets, websocket

I'm having problems to connect with socket.

This is the error i'm getting on browser.
[socket error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urCMI.jpg)

This is my spring socket config

```
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class ChatSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/chat");
    }

    /**
     * Register the endpoint where the socket will call to connect
     */
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat-connect").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
```

I'm using sockjs-client v1.0.3, running the java application in a tomcat 8, linux ec2 on aws.

Any help on how to solve this problem?

**EDITED**

On server, THe only log I see is "Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null"

Answer (score 1):

Check your Apache httpd.conf to make sure your redirects are not causing the problem.

You should have something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
```

Are you seeing this for WS & WSS?

Another possibility, especially if you're trying to communicate with secure sockets, is that your Apache proxy is trying to handle the security while passing unsecured content to your services. This will interfere with the handshaking that upgrades the http connection to a websocket, since once it's a websocket, Apache is bypassed. Instead, you should divert the socket to a secure port on your server (e.g. Tomcat, or whatever is hosting the websocket server) and let your server handle the upgrade.

Comment: can you check my last question please